# Efficiently "Hash" Set of Values to Indice

Tags: c++, hash, lookup, lookup-tables

First of all, a disclaimer; hash is a somewhat inaccurate term for what I'm aiming for, please, feel free to suggest a better title.

At any rate, I'm currently attempting to program a complex spatial algorithm running in real-time. In order to save cycles, I've decided to generate a lookup table that contains all of the 32,000 possibilities.

If I were to do this conventionally, the values(Inclusive range and field count) 2x +0 -> +15 and 3x -2 -> +2 would be mapped to two four-bit and three three-bit values respectively, giving me a lookup-table size of 2 ^ (2*4 + 3*3) = 131,072 entries, a nearly **410% waste**.

Given the nature of the algorithm, collisions would absolutely cripple its functionality (so no traditional hash functions unless I could guarantee no collisions with all relevant values). Beyond that, the structure I'm working with is rather large (ie, I would /really/ like to avoid allocating any more than 200% of what I need). Finally, since this table will be referenced so often, I'd like to avoid the overhead of a traditional hash-table in both bucket lookups and an excessively complex hash function.

Having taken a more traditional computer-science approach, I'm beginning to strongly believe the solution lies in some mathematics of base-conversion I'm completely ignorant of. Any idea if this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate an index the same way you calculated the maximum number of combinations, by multiplying each element. Take each element from most significant to least significant, add a constant to make it range from 0 to n-1, and multiply by the number of combinations remaining.

Given your 0 to 15 values of a, b (range of 16) and -2 to +2 values of c, d, e (range of 5):

```
index = a * 16*5*5*5 + b * 5*5*5 + (c+2) * 5*5 + (d+2) * 5 + (e+2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mark! I figured it out a moment ago as well, although the solution I implemented was slightly different. Since the two 16-range values could simply be concatenated and mapped to a single byte, allowing for a simplified U7b(c+d*5+e*5*5)
Forgive my apparent lack of taking seventh grade math, I guess haha?